# Oracle ODBC connection to SQL Server: Table Name Length Issues

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc

I'm running into a problem when accessing a SQL Server table from an Oracle setup via ODBC.

I can access 90% of the tables absolutely fine, but there's a few tables that have a name that's longer than 30 characters.  Whenever I try to interact with the table (describes, selects, etc) Oracle throws an "identifier too long" error and gives up.

Is there a way to coax Oracle into playing nice with the SQL Server tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we are talking about an Oracle database that has a database link created to a SQL Server database via Heterogeneous Services, you would need to write code using the [`DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH` package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_hspass.htm) to interact with the tables in question.  You'd also need to use this package if you have tables where there are column names that are not valid Oracle identifiers.

Comment: Wow, that really adds a layer of complexity.  Suddenly doing a "create table ____ as select" is a lot more roundabout.

Comment: @GigaWatt - Yeah.  It's definitely not as slick.  But it's not that bad if you've ever done anything with `DBMS_SQL` or with a client API like OCI-- it's very similar.